# find the next greater number that can be formed using digits 7 and 9

Tags: c++, c, arrays, numbers

I came accross this question in an interview. some test cases that were provided were
ip: 6
op:7
ip:8
op:9
ip:57
op:77
I couldnt think of how to approach it. if someone can provide the pseudo code that will be great.

Comment: `while (!uses_only_7_or_9(++ip)) /* void */;`

Comment: @prng It's OK, yet only if complexity not matters.

Answer (score 0):

Find the most significant non 7/9 digit, and increase it to 7 if below 7, else increase it to 9. All digits to the right of it => 7.

Comment: Have to add `+1` as first step, to make sure the resulting number is not equal to starting one.

Comment: most significant -> least significant. typo?

Comment: @ArnonZilca certainly not! think about it, what would you then do about the more significant digits that are still not 7/9? those you need to fix aswell. since you eventually have to increment your number, you are free to fix the less significant digits at 7.

Comment: Right! looked at it the wrong way. just missing scenario of a number that all of its digits are 7/9. adding 1 as @user4419802 commented sounds right.